# How to handel dynamically changing elements in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click all products in the search item but those product id value are unique how do i click each element dynamically here is the id value `//*[@id='889401']/a/div[2]`here
889401 this id value changing for every item how can i capture those id value do click operation plz help me.
Here is the html line.

```
<a class="hit-ss-logger" pos="0;732" pogid="889401" categoryid="57" v="p" href="http://www.snapdeal.com/product/samsung-np300e5xa0bin-laptop-2nd-gen/889401?pos=0;732">
```

Comment: There will be a way but you will need to think about the **whole page structure** and how that anchor fits into it. E.g is it within a `div` that you can reliably hook onto?

Comment: Can you please post atleast the html for couple of products?

Comment: If the ID is dynamically generated, find another attribute to select on.  Trying to keep track of IDs makes a mess of code IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can catch all elements (filtering with class="hit-ss-logger" for example)

```
array = driver.findElements(By.className("hit-ss-logger"));
```

write all on an array and using a loop you can click all of them.

Hope it helps